# How to calculate circuit noise in dB from measurement

Tags: adc, noise

I've never quite understood how to calculate the noise in dB from an analog circuit at the output of the ADC.

This is my measurement:
[image: measurement]

It is a 16bit ADC, as we can see there is roughly a +/-1 bit, or +/-2 bits, depending on what sigma is considered for the distribution.

Here is the data distribution:
[image: distribution]

One bit is equal to 1, the signal is at around 40'000.

Comment: dB is a relative metric i.e. a ratio. This is typically a Signal to Noise Ratio (SNR) or measured against a know level like dBu or dBV. I think you want SNR and so should measure the RMS amplitude of your signal and compare it to the RMS amplitude of your noise.

Comment: In this measurement, it is count, so one bit is 1, signal is about 40'000

Comment: Would this 10 log(40000 ÷ 1.5) = 44dB be correct, I'm not sure about what sigma/distribution to take the noise level.

Comment: So you want [dBFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBFS). 16 bit is 2^16 or 65536, but as you are using bipolar it is half this, or 32768. For peak then you have a visible noise peak of about 3, 20*log10(3/32768) = -80dBFS. Really I would recommend finding the RMS of your noise signal though as a peak value isn't really representative of noise.

Comment: @loudnoises it's bipolar but not centered, the center point is at 0 and it goes to -11'000.

Comment: Apologies I somehow missed your comment about the signal. I really feel I do not have enough information to answer your question. A representation of bipolar signals that is not symmetric is highly unusual, and I don't have enough specifications about the format to answer. If instead you meant that the format is symmetric, but with the signal extending between 40e3 and -11e3 then I'm not sure how that works as it exceeds the limits of a 16 bit system.

Comment: 16bit system has a range of 65535, the circuit is designed so the 0V is actually at 11e3, signal is at around 51e3 if we look at absolute values.